# Almost all subgroups of a Lie group are free

Tags: measure-theory, manifolds, lie-groups

I am currently reading [this paper](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/256205013_Almost_all_subgroups_of_a_Lie_group_are_free) by Epstein. I need help with understanding the proof. Specifically, I have the following two questions.

1. Let $w\colon G\to H$ be an analytic mapping between connected Lie groups $G$ and $H$. How do we prove that the preimage of a point is either the whole of $G$ or has Haar measure zero in $G$?
   The paper says one should take $G$ to be an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^m$ and use induction on $m$ and Fubini's theorem, but this doesn't really convince me (I cannot fill the details).
2. The whole paper seems to assume that $G$ is analytic manifold, whereas the usual assumption is that Lie group is smooth manifold. Does this mean that the result of the paper hold only for real-analytic Lie groups, or this assumption is not actually a restriction and in some way we also have the claim for the classical real Lie groups?

<s>**Edit:** Actually, regarding (1), I don't see why the usual $t\in\mathbb{R}\mapsto e^{-1/t^2}1_{t>0}\in\mathbb{R}$ is not a counterexample.</s>

Comment: Oh, sorry, I've deleted my answer, which assumed you meant $w$ to be a Lie group homomorphism.  My answer to 2 still applies, though: $C^\infty$ Lie groups can always be given real analytic structures.

Comment: Isn't your counterexample injective?

Comment: It isn't injective (it's $0$ on $(-\infty,0)$), but the problem is that it isn't analytic.

Comment: @Timkinsella: actually, $C^2$ is enough, and the analytic structure is unique. See http://mathoverflow.net/q/49587/54415 (and I think I recall my Lie group lecturer saying that it is true even for $C^1$ groups, but with much harder proof).

Comment: @tomasz Sure, since $C^1 \implies C^\infty$ right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Work in Euclidean space and write $w=(w^1(x_1,...x_n),...w^m(x_1,...,x_n))$.  Write any $w^i$ as a power series in $x_n$ with coefficients as power series in the other variables: $$w^i=\sum_j c_j(x_1,...,x_{n-1})x_n^j$$

Then by Fubini, if $w^i$ vanishes on a set of positive measure, there exists a set of positive measure $A\subset \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ such that for any $\overline{a} \in A$, the analytic function $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}, t \mapsto w^i(\overline{a}, t)$ vanishes on a set of positive measure.  But then this $w^i(\overline{a}, \cdot )$ vanishes identically, so that each coefficient $c_j$ vanishes on $A$.  Then by induction, each $c_j$ is identically zero on $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$, so that $w^i$ is identically zero.

Comment: This sounds plausible for Euclidean spaces, but how do you make transfer from Lie group to Euclidean space in terms of measure? That is, the missing detail I don't see here is how to relate Haar measure with Lebesgue measure using coordinate maps (which, as far as I know, are not assumed to be measure preserving or somethin like that)?

Comment: @FilantoRenika Good question.  Fact: if $A\subset G$ has (Lebesgue) measure zero in every chart, then $A$ has Haar measure zero. Proof: Let the Haar measure be represented by a volume form $\Omega$, and assume $A$ is contained in a single chart $x: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$.  Then the Haar measure of $A$ is gotten by (Lebesgue) integrating the function function $\Omega (\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1},...,\frac{\partial}{\partial x_n})$ over $x(A)$.  This is zero since $x(A)$ has Lebesgue measure zero.  Does this make sense? I hope my notation isn't too sloppy.

Comment: In general, I think the set of "measure zero" subsets of a smooth manifold does not depend on the regular Borel measure chosen.  But I'm not completely certain about that.