# Measure of inverse image of points by an analytic mapping

Tags: measure-theory, manifolds, analyticity

How can one prove the following statement: For any analytic mapping from a connected analytic manifold $M$ to an analytic
manifold $N$, the inverse image of a point in $N$ is either the whole of $M$ or has
measure zero in $M$.
The hint is taking $M$ to be an open subset
of $\mathbb{R}^m$ and using induction on $m$, and Fubini’s theorem. But I can't fill in the details.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of suggesting an edit to make your title more informative.  Feel free to change it if you feel it does not do justice to your question.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/896023/almost-all-subgroups-of-a-lie-group-are-free/896676#896676